# Create a pandas dataframe column of variable sized lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, explode

I need to create a dataframe that contains all possible start times for a scheduler for some machines. My initial dataframe (msDF) contains three simple columns:

- MachID - the ID of each machine
- Start - the starting datetime that the machine is available for scheduling
- slots - the number of slots available starting from that time

msDF is copied from a master dataframe, but for illustration, it may look like this:

```
msDF = pd.DataFrame({ 'MachID': [1,2,3,4,5],
                      'Start': ["02/04/2021 9:00","06/04/2021 12:30","09/04/2021 10:00", \
                                "12/04/2021 11:00","15/04/2021 08:00"],
                      'slots': [2, 3, 4, 3, 1]})
```

|  | MachID | Start | slots |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 02/04/2021 9:00 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 06/04/2021 12:30 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 09/04/2021 10:00 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | 12/04/2021 11:00 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 15/04/2021 08:00 | 1 |

I need to explode this dataframe so that each row is duplicated "slots" times with a slotIndex. The desired output is:

|  | MachID | Start | slots | SlotIndex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 02/04/2021 9:00 | 2 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 02/04/2021 9:00 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 06/04/2021 12:30 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 06/04/2021 12:30 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 06/04/2021 12:30 | 3 | 2 |

My approach is problematic.  I am creating variable length lists into the SlotIndex and exploding them, but this creates warnings.

To do this, I use:

```
msDF['SlotIndex'] = None
for x in msDF.index:
    msDF.SlotIndex.loc[x] = list(range(msDF.loc[x,'slots']))
```

It works but with warnings :
*SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame*

I later explode msDF to get the result I want:

```
msDF = msDF.explode('SlotIndex')
```

How can this be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use repeat.

```
df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.slots)]
```

The index will be repeated. So you can use that to set the slot id.

```
df['slot_id'] = 1
df['slot_id'] = df.groupby(df.index)['slot_id'].transform('cumsum')
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you @soumith. It was really fast too.

Comment: I have updated the answer. This is one way to go about it.

Comment: That revision gives exactly the result I was aiming for and I never would have come up with it myself. I took your first answer based on repeat and then create a new index that I modulo'd against slots to create the slot_id, but the groupby method is cleaner and deliver the outcome I wanted. Thanks again - I have been stuck on this for a while. My original solution worked in testing and failed in operation for reasons I cannot understand. Yours is working through-and-through.

Comment: Glad it helped!